# React Native Advice - Firing Redux Action OnPress Dispatch Action

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I am new to using Redux within a React Native application. I require some advice on how I am firing off my redux action when the user presses a button within the app.

I have a Sign In screen whereby the user enters their username and password, which fires off a `fetchData` Redux action on button press. The `fetchData` action uses Redux Saga to make an API request to valid the user and if valid an "auth_token" will be returned.

What I would like to achieve is if an auth token is returned, the user will be redirected to another screen within my `onPress` function.

Here is my code so far...

**Sign In Screen**

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React, { Component} from 'react';
import { Container } from '../components/Container';
import { StatusBar, Text, TextInput, Button } from 'react-native';
import { setItem } from '../storage/sensitive'
import { connectAlert } from "../components/Alert";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { fetchData } from "../redux/actions/userLogin";

class SignIn extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        navigation: PropTypes.object,
        dispatch: PropTypes.func,
        authToken: PropTypes.string,
        //appData: PropTypes.object
    };

    state = {
        username: '',
        password: '',
        error: '',
        appData: {}
    }

    componentWillMount() {

    }

    onPressSignIn = () => {
        // Check if the username and password fields are entered.
        if (this.state.username === '' || this.state.password === '') {
            this.setState({error: 'Please ensure you have entered a username and password '});
        }
        else {
            // Remove error message if one was rendered previously.
            this.setState({error: ''})

            // Send user credentials to loginUser function to retrieve Authentication Token.
            this.props.dispatch(fetchData(this.state.username, this.state.password));

            // HOW?: Output 'this.props.appData.data.user.auth_token' to determine whether the user is valid
            //        If valid redirect to another screen.
        }

    };

    render() {
         let test = this.props.appData;
         console.log('Get Auth Token', test.data.user ? test.data.user.auth_token : 'no token');
        return (
            <Container>
                <StatusBar barStyle="default" />
                <Text>Sign In</Text>
                <TextInput style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
                           placeholder="Username"
                           value={this.state.username}
                           email-address={true}
                           onChangeText={username => this.setState({username})} />
                <TextInput style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
                           placeholder="Password"
                           value={this.state.password}
                           onChangeText={password => this.setState({password})}
                           secureTextEntry={true} />
                <Button onPress={this.onPressSignIn} title="Sign In" color="#841584" accessibilityLabel="Sign in to your account" />
                {this.state.error &&
                    <TextInput value={this.state.error} />
                }
                {this.state.appData.isFetching && <TextInput value='Loading' />}
            </Container>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) =>  {
    console.log('mapStateToProps', state);
    return {
        appData: state.userLoginReducer
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(connectAlert(SignIn));
```

**Reducer (if it helps)**

```
import { FETCHING_DATA, FETCHING_DATA_SUCCESS, FETCHING_DATA_FAILURE } from '../actions/userLogin'

const initialState = {
    data: [],
    username: '',
    password: '',
    dataFetched: false,
    isFetching: false,
    error: false
}

const userLoginReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCHING_DATA:
            return {
                ...state,
                data: [],
                isFetching: true,
                username: action.username,
                password: action.password
            }
        case FETCHING_DATA_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                isFetching: false,
                data: action.result
            }
        case FETCHING_DATA_FAILURE:
            return {
                ...state,
                isFetching: false,
                error: true
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default userLoginReducer;
```

What I am noticing when the user presses `onPressSignIn` function, the "auth_token" is never returned. However, it is returned within the render() area.

Do I need to make my checks to determine at this point to determine if the user was successful in their login? It is only here where I am getting the success response back from my Redux action type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not very familiar with `redux-saga` but I will tell you what I would do if my fetch request returned a Promise or if it didn't. In case your fetch request returned a `Promise` it would look something like this (keep in mind that I usally use the `bindActionCreators` method to map dispatch to props):

```
 onPressSignIn = () => {
   if (this.state.username === '' || this.state.password === '') {
     this.setState({error: 'Please ensure you have entered a username and password '});
   } else {
     this.setState({error: ''})

     fetchData(this.state.username, this.state.password)
       .then(res => {
         // Here you can have all kinds of logic to decide if
         // redirect should occur or not
         if (res.isUserAuthenticated) redirectTo('/anotherScreen');
       });
 };
```

otherwise I would simply use `componentDidUpdate`:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  // At this point your props are up to date as this lifecycle method
  // is called every time your component receives new props
  const test = this.props.appData;
  if (test.data.user.auth_token) redirectTo('/anotherScreen');
}
```

in this case your `onPressSignIn` would not change.

Comment: That looks very elegant solution to what I need. Do you think I'm over engineering my solution using Redux? I'm questioning whether I'm using it just because it seems to be the  recommended approach to state management.

Comment: Well I am not aware of your app as a whole so I can't give you a straight answer. I would recommend reading a few articles directly from the docs (here is a useful link https://redux.js.org/#before-proceeding-further). It all depends on the scale of your app and the problems you face in state management, prop drilling, state lifting, and so on...

Comment: Also mark this answer as correct if you think it is satisfactory! =D